# Devextreme dxForm getting undefined when tried to access

Tags: jquery, asp.net, devexpress, devextreme

This is the code i am trying to run. Seems like the dxForm is not working, and i am getting undefined when i try to access it. I am not sure what i have left out. I do import devextreme js and css. If that anything else i needed to import in order to make dxForm work properly?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var myForm = $("#myFormContainer").dxForm({
                formData: {
                    firstName: "John",
                    lastName: "Heart",
                    phone: "+1(213) 555-9392",
                    email: "jheart@dx-email.com"
                },
                items: ["firstName", "lastName", {
                    itemType: "group",
                    caption: "Contacts",
                    name: "groupName",
                    items: ["phone", "email"]
                }]
            }).dxForm("instance");

            // Accessing the dxForm instance
            // You can now use the 'myForm' variable to interact with the form

            // Example: Getting form data
            var formData = myForm.option("groupName.phone", "visible", false);
            console.log(formData);
```

Error:

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'option') TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'option')
```

Comment: Try using this instead: myForm.itemOption("groupName.phone", { "visible": false });